# Problem in understanding Centralizer and Normlizer in Lattice structure.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am studying from Dummit and Foote where in second chapter there is topic of Lattice of subgroups of groups. I know how the lattice is drawn, but I don't know how to find centralizer or normalizer  from the lattice diagram. Book explains how it's possible to find out centralizers and normalizer from the lattice, but gives only example of $D_8$ centralizer. I don't know how they did it.

I just want to know how to find centralizer and normalizer from lattice, if you know any online or offline resources for this it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in Dummit & Foote (my copy 3rd ed. p.71), you need to do *some* computations, it cannot be read off immediately, it is not a free lunch. For example, if $A$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$, then $A \subseteq C_G(A)$ and given the lattice, this leaves you with a couple of possibilities for the centralizer. But it is not clear from this point which one to choose. For that you need more information about the group structure, as Dummit & Foote point out with the example of $D_8$.

Comment: So here if I took any subgroup from lattice and just take generator of that subgroup and commute with other subgroup generator, and if it commutes will that satisfy normalizer property?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you focus on a particular subgroup $H$ and you can find a $g \in G$ that commutes with (the generators of) $H$, then $g$ centralizes $H$. Normalizing is a different matter (you need to look for elements $g$ with $H^g=H$), but always $C_G(H) \subseteq N_G(H)$, so you can inspect subgroups lying above the centralizer in the lattice.

Comment: I got what you are saying for centralizer but how normalizer is found i didn't got that. You said $H^g=H$. As per my knowledge we could take exponent as integer number but you are taking exponent to be group element g, $H^g$. How is that possible?

Comment: Ah, that is a matter of notation: usually, $H^g=gHg^{-1}$ and hence $N_G(H)=\{g \in g: gH=Hg\}$, note that $H^g=H$ is equivalent to $gH=Hg$ (put differently, the left and right coset with representative $g$ are the same). See D&F Chapter 2.2.

Comment: Oh, got i didn't knew that, Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You are welcome!! Glad you learned something and keep asking questions!